# Schedule a macro in an excel saved in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with a macro that I would like to run twice a day automatically. The file is shared in a Sharepoint 2013 site. Is it possible to schedule this macro? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in an automatic way from SharePoint.  You can use a Powershell script that could run the macro in the Excel file.

Here is a link to a sample script:

https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/script_library/m/sharepoint/10674

Running the script at a specific time can be done using custom SharePoint Timer Jobs, or a batch file that runs on the server using task scheduler.

You'll have to have the skill to modify the script for your needs and also the access to the server to run the script.

[Executing powershell script from a timer job](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12236/executing-powershell-script-from-a-timer-job)